# Autofac: resolving different params to object using DependencyResolver

Tags: autofac

I am building an MVC application and have the need to send a different cachecontext (wraps info on which cache to use) into my repositories using the DependencyResolver.  There are 10 different types of cachecontexts that can be passed in.  At the moment, I am using 10 different registrations for 10 different types of interfaces (ICacheContexts).  This works but does not seem like the correct way of handling this circumstance.  Is there a way to create a factory that knows the object type it is being passed to so I can just determine the correct CacheContext to return and thus only have one registration to maintain?

Current code:

```
builder.Register(c => new CacheContext(AppConfig.AppBucketName, AppConfig.AppBucketpassword))
                .As<ICacheContextForApps>();
builder.Register(c => new CacheContext(AppConfig.AcctBucketName, AppConfig.AcctBucketpassword))
                .As<ICacheContextForAccounts>();
etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this from the repository side - for each repository, configure its parameters to resolve the right cache context. E.g. (paraphrasing)

```
builder.Register(c => new CacheContext(...for appls...))
    .Named<ICacheContext>("apps");

builder.RegisterType<AppsRepository>()
    .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ICacheContext),
                   (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<ICacheContext>("apps"));
```

Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Now that is a thing of beauty.  I had glanced at WithParameter but didn't think it would help.  So I should be able to use RegisterAssemblyTypes with AsImplementedAssemblies to autoregister my assemblies to the correct CacheContext based on say the namespace?  That is definitely far more elegant than the road I was taking.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped - yes, both the Named() part on the cache context, and the choice of service name on the repository side, should be able to be rigged up to apply a convention if need be. Cheers!